# Why function in Javascript file does not load in master page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page that has javascript files added with `asp:ScriptReference`, but in `document.ready ( $(function(){}) )` the functions defined in the Javascript file do not load, and I get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'nanoScroller'.

Whereas the same code runs in other simple projects.

Comment: Check the necessary `script files for nanoscroller` are added in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Dear friend if you are using `ajaxtoolkite` and you are using `updatepanel` or `scriptmanager` then jquery make a conflict with it so you can use the following 2 method to make your code work properly the bellow code will solve your problem

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// bind your jQuery events here initially
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function() {
// re-bind your jQuery events here
});
```

Comment: yes i use scriptmanager when i add this line $(".nano").nanoScroller(); in $(document).ready the same error is raised but i dont understand where add second method (var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
// re-bind your jQuery events here
});) and where run this

Comment: dear @A.Alexandri in ajaxtoolkint and in script manager there own java script events take place and our custom jquery not working properly thas way we have to fire our jquery script in the endrequst event